Difficulty creating file in exe on emu8086
I am trying to take user input and put it into a created file, but it is returning this error:
file does not exist:
C:\emu8086\vdrive
\emu8086\vdrive\C\inventory.txt
interrupt error: 21h/3Dh : cannot open file.
I can see the file in the given path though.. so I'm confused. The file does not have the information it is supposed to.
Anyways, here's the lengthy code:
.model small
.stack 100h
.data
    ; Memory blocks to simulate the structure
    manufacturer  db 20          ; Maximum input size
                 db 20 dup(0)    ; Buffer for input 

    model        db 20
                 db 20 dup(0)

    color        db 20
                 db 20 dup(0)

    engine_size  db 10           ; Smaller buffer for engine size
                 db 10 dup(0)

    doors        db 2
                 db 2 dup(0)

    filename      db 'C:\emu8086\vdrive\C\inventory.txt', 0 
    continue_buffer db 2, 2 dup(0)  ; Buffer for Y/N prompt input

    prompt_msg1   db 'Enter manufacturer: $'  
    prompt_msg2   db 'Enter model: $'    
    prompt_msg3   db 'Enter color: $'  
    prompt_msg4   db 'Enter engine size: $' 
    prompt_msg5   db 'Enter number of doors: $' 
    continue_prompt db 'Add more inventory (Y/N)? $'

    newline       db 0Dh, 0Ah, '$'    ; Newline characters to move to next line
    done_msg      db '*** Awesome Auto Lot Inventory file has been processed ***', 0Dh, 0Ah, '$'    
    
    
    ;For file reading and writing
    file_handle dw ?
    bytes_written dw ?
    buffer_size db 70
    read_buffer db 70 dup(0)

.code
main:   
; Initialize data segment
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax     
    
;Create file
mov ah, 3Ch   ;Create file  
lea dx, filename   
mov cx, 0     
int 21h
mov file_handle, ax ;save file handle 
    
    

    ; Main loop
main_loop:   

    call get_auto_info   ; Call procedure to get automobile information
    call write_to_file

    ; Ask user if they want to add more inventory
    lea dx, continue_prompt
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h

    ; Get user input for continue prompt (Y/N)
    lea dx, continue_buffer
    mov ah, 0Ah
    int 21h

    ; Check if the user entered 'N'
    mov al, continue_buffer + 2  ; Get the first character entered ('Y' or 'N')
    cmp al, 'N'
    je close_file       ; If user entered 'N', jump to done  
    
    
    lea dx, newline  ; If yes, move next prompt to next line
    mov ah,09h
    int 21h
    

    
    jmp main_loop  ;If not, continue 
    
    
    
close_file:
    mov ah, 3Eh
    mov bx, file_handle
    int 21h

    lea dx, done_msg    ;print done message
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h  
    
    
    ;open file to read
    
    mov ah, 3Dh           ; Open file function
    lea dx, filename
    mov al, 0            ; Read only
    int 21h
    mov file_handle, ax   ; Save the file handle   
    
    
 read_loop:
    call read_from_file      ;read structure from file
    cmp al, 0                ;check if end of file
    je done_reading          ;if yes, jump to done
    
    ;Print structure
    call print_auto_info 
    
    ;loop to read more data
    jmp read_loop  
    
    
done_reading:
;Close file
mov ah, 3Eh
mov bx, file_handle
int 21h    
    
;end prog
    mov ah, 4Ch
    int 21h   
    



; Procedure to collect automobile information
get_auto_info proc
    ; Prompt for manufacturer       
    lea dx, prompt_msg1
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h

    ; User input for manufacturer
    lea dx, manufacturer
    mov ah, 0Ah
    int 21h

    ; Move to the next line after user input
    lea dx, newline
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h

    ; Prompt for model
    lea dx, prompt_msg2
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h

    ; User input for model
    lea dx, model
    mov ah, 0Ah
    int 21h

    ; Move to the next line after user input
    lea dx, newline
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h

    ; Prompt for color
    lea dx, prompt_msg3
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h

    ; User input for color
    lea dx, color
    mov ah, 0Ah
    int 21h

    ; Move to the next line after user input
    lea dx, newline
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h

    ; Prompt for engine size
    lea dx, prompt_msg4
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h

    ; User input for engine size
    lea dx, engine_size
    mov ah, 0Ah
    int 21h

    ; Move to the next line after user input
    lea dx, newline
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h

    ; Prompt for number of doors
    lea dx, prompt_msg5
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h

    ; User input for number of doors
    lea dx, doors
    mov ah, 0Ah
    int 21h

    ; Move to the next line after user input
    lea dx, newline
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h

    ret
get_auto_info endp   

;Write structure to file
write_to_file proc
    ; Prepare the combined data for writing
    lea si, manufacturer  ; Start with manufacturer
    lea di, read_buffer   ; Point to buffer for writing
    mov cx, 20            ; Size of manufacturer
    rep movsb             ; Copy manufacturer to buffer

    lea si, model         ; Next, copy model
    mov cx, 20
    rep movsb

    lea si, color         ; Next, copy color
    mov cx, 20
    rep movsb

    lea si, engine_size   ; Next, copy engine size
    mov cx, 10
    rep movsb

    lea si, doors         ; Finally, copy doors
    mov cx, 2
    rep movsb

    ; Write to file
    mov ah, 40h           ; Function to write to file
    mov bx, file_handle   ; File handle
    lea dx, read_buffer   ; Pointer to the data buffer
    mov cx, 70            ; Number of bytes to write
    int 21h               ; Call DOS interrupt
    mov bytes_written, ax  ; Save number of bytes written

    ret
write_to_file endp

    ; Read automobile structure from file 
read_from_file proc  
    
    ; Read from file
    mov ah, 3Fh                   ; Read from file function
    mov bx, file_handle          
    lea dx, read_buffer           ; Point to buffer
    mov cx, 70                    ; Number of bytes to read
    int 21h
    ret
read_from_file endp
                    
; Write data to file
write_data proc
    ; Write to file
    mov ah, 40h              ; Function to write to file
    mov bx, file_handle
    int 21h                  ; Call DOS interrupt
    ret
write_data endp



; Print automobile information
print_auto_info proc
    ; Print the manufacturer
    lea dx, read_buffer           ; Point to buffer
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h
    ; Print a new line
    lea dx, newline
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h

    ; Print model
    lea dx, read_buffer + 20     ; Adjust to the model position
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h
    ; Print a new line
    lea dx, newline
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h

    ; Print color
    lea dx, read_buffer + 40     ; Adjust to the color position
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h
    ; Print a new line
    lea dx, newline
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h

    ; Print engine size
    lea dx, read_buffer + 60     ; Adjust to the engine size position
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h
    ; Print a new line
    lea dx, newline
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h

    ; Print doors
    lea dx, read_buffer + 70     ; Adjust to the doors position
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h
    ; Print a new line
    lea dx, newline
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h
    
    ret
print_auto_info endp

end main
                
    


You should properly setup buffers for service ah = 0ah, int 21h:
buffer        db 20            ; 19 characters + enter (0x0d)
              db ?             ; number of chars without enter
              db 20 dup(0)     ; chars + 0x0d

In your code the second byte erroneously gets combined with the data buffer, so after int 21h the last character 0x0d will be stored where filename begins. The pathname will be overwritten.

doors         db 2
              db 2 dup(0)

filename      db 'C:\emu8086\vdrive\C\inventory.txt', 0 



Example:
Enter number of doors: 3 + Enter (0x0d)

Buffer doors will look like this:
doors         db 2             ; 0x02 - number of chars + 0x0d
              db 2 dup(0)      ; 0x01 - number of chars entered by user
                               ; 0x33 - start of data, only one char
                               ; 0x0d - and CR will be here --+
                                                              |   
                  +-------------------------------------------+
                  |                                           
                  v (wrong pathname)
filename      db 'X:\emu8086\vdrive\C\inventory.txt', 0 

